# UI Router fails to update URL in address bar after successful state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm building a small Angular app and I'm currently using ui-router.

I've hit a problem which looks awfully like a bug in ui-router but I can't be sure as I'm not that familiar with this library. When the user clicks on a specific link, although the correct view state gets loaded as expected, the URL in the address bar doesn't get updated.

I'm using ui-router's `ui-sref` directive to automatically generate the URL for the state. For example in the checklist list view I use the following code:

```
<a ui-sref="checklist-phase({ aircraftId: checklist.aircraft, checklistId: checklist.id, phaseSlug: checklist.phases[0].slug })" ng-bind="checklist.name"></a>
```

I've cut down my app and made it into a Plunker so the problem is hopefully reproducible by others. The issue can also be observed in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW9CFe6LfCw

**Reproduction steps:**

1. Go to http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/ZqMIYNU6abEAndAM5nx1/#/aircraft/1/checklists
2. Click the first link. Notice that the view updates to show the correct state, but the URL remains at `/#/aircraft/1/checklists`.

What is strange is that navigating back to this state by other means updates the URL perfectly. For example (assuming steps 1 and 2 above have been followed):

1. Scroll to the bottom and click the `Next Phase` link. Note that the state changes and the URL updates.
2. Scroll down on this new view and click `Previous Phase`. Note that the previous state reloads and this time the URL it updated correctly.

Am I using ui-router incorrectly or doing something else incorrectly to cause this behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure whats happening, but instead of specifying parent in the `$stateProvider.state(...)` function, I always specify the parent in the state name itself. like `'checklist-detail.checklist-phase'`. Don't know if this will fix the problem, but your app could benefit from this. Your state names could become `checklists`, `checklists.detail`, `checklists.detail.phase` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bra44NhzbTP05puorAZ?p=preview) updated version

On your state `'check-lists'` you provide ui-sref to `'checklist-phase'`

```
<a ui-sref="checklist-phase({ aircraftId: ...
```

And the `'checklist-phase'` is defined as a child state of `'checklist-detail'`

```
.state('checklist-phase', {
    parent: 'checklist-detail',
```

And the state `'checklist-detail'` has controller which calls $state.go

```
.state('checklist-detail', {       
    controller: 'ChecklistDetailCtrl',
    ...

    .controller('ChecklistDetailCtrl', function ($scope.... 
    {

        $state.go('checklist-phase', {
            phaseSlug: checklistData.phases[0].slug
        }, {
            location: 'replace'
        });
```

Do NOT do that... just remove the `$state.go` - because you are already navigating to the `checklist-phase` *(see the first lines above)* ... check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bra44NhzbTP05puorAZ?p=preview)

Comment: Oops.

I totally forgot I had a call to $state.go in the controller. It didn't occur to me that could be the cause. Thanks!

The reason that $state.go call is there was to try and redirect a visit to `/aircraft/:aircraftId/checklist/:checklistId` to `/aircraft/:aircraftId/checklist/:checklistId/phase/:firstPhaseSlug` so that the URL structure didn't seem broken. Is there a way to achieve this without breaking the checklist-detail state as I did in the original question?

Comment: Wish to help you, but not sure if I understand... what my updated plunker shows is workign solution... is not it? Do you need something else? because, the `ui-sref` is enough. It is in fact the same as the $state.go(). Other words, I am not sure what is still not .... as you like ;)

Comment: Yes your solution solves the problem :).  

In my previous comment I was explaining why I used the $state.go function. I was fully aware that ui-sref used it internally to actually do the routing.  

My call to $state.go was to try and catch the case of the user visiting a URL like: `http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/8bra44NhzbTP05puorAZ/#/aircraft/1/checklist/1/`. Currently hitting this URL just redirects to the aircraft screen. I was trying to make the app redirect to the correct first phase automatically in this situation.